# Preventing Visual Studio 2022 From Automatic Copying of Unwanted DLLs to Release Folder

Tags: visual-studio, qt, visual-c++, dll, build

I have integrated Qt6 into Visual Studio C++ 2022. My project uses Qt6.5/VTK9.2 library to visualize a volumetric image dataset. Compilation and build are done successfully.

The issue that I have is the DLLs that are automatically copied into the Release folder and I don't know where they are coming from because they have conflicts with the generated executable.

In order for me to run the executable I need to manually copy the correct DLLs into the Release folder to be able to run it. By doing so, the app works beautifully.

I can create a post-event build but this is a hack and I want to avoid it. With every new build, the incompatibility comes back and I have to copy the correct DLLs again, every single time.

How can I know where those DLLs are coming from and prevent them from getting copied to the Release folder? I have made sure the `Register Output` option in the project properties is set to `No` but still it copies DLLs from other locations.

Really appreciate any tips.